# Keep recording audio while navigating to another screen

Tags: ios, swift, audio, avfoundation, avaudiosession

I want to continue an `AVAudioSession` that I started in one screen to (recording using `AVAudioRecorder`) while navigating to another screen and back. Is that possible?
Because I am always getting a shorter  file.

session start / recording start

```
  func startRecording() {
    let session = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
    do {
        try session.setCategory(AVAudioSession.Category.playAndRecord, mode: .default)
        try session.setActive(true)
        let settings = [AVFormatIDKey: Int(kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC),
                        AVSampleRateKey: 44100,
                        AVNumberOfChannelsKey: 2,
                        AVEncoderAudioQualityKey: AVAudioQuality.high.rawValue]
        audioRecorder = try AVAudioRecorder(url: getAudioFileUrl(), settings: settings)
        audioRecorder?.delegate = self
        audioRecorder?.record()
        isRecording = true
    }
    catch let error {
        print(error)
    }
}
```

the recorder (the. audio recorder is part. of it:

```
class RecorderManager: NSObject {

static let shared = RecorderManager()

private var recordTimer : Timer?
private var recordTimerValue: Double?
private var audioRecorder = AudioRecordedManager()
private var videoRecorder = ScreenRecorderManager()
```

this is how the record start.  in screen A :

```
 func startRecord(view: UIView){
    self.recordTimerValue = Double(0)
    
    if (self.recordTimer != nil){
        self.recordTimer?.invalidate()
        self.recordTimer = nil
    }
    
    self.showCounterAnimation(view: view, doneCallback: {
        
        self.videoRecorder.recordingSetup()
        self.audioRecorder.startRecording()
        self.videoRecorder.startRecording {

            if (self.recordTimer == nil){
                self.recordTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1.0,
                                                        target: self,
                                                        selector: #selector(self.onTimerFires),
                                                        userInfo: nil,
                                                        repeats: true)
            }
        }
    })
    
}
```

this is the transition to screen B :

```
   if let item = self.videoItem{
        if let listItem = self.videoListItem{
            if let videoLOcalUrl = self.videoLocalUrl{
                let vc:SplitViewController  = SplitViewController()
                vc.currentTimeValue = currentTimeValue
                playVideoViewModel.pause()
                vc.videoModel = SplitViewModel(videoItem: item, videoListItem: listItem, videoLocalUrl: videoLOcalUrl)
                vc.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
                self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure it's possible. Instead of writing your sound recording code in your view controller, create a sound recording class. Make it a singleton. Trigger the sound recording from your view controller, and leave it running when you move to a different screen.

Comment: i actually did that  ...still s, for some reason , the recording stops

Comment: You have a bug on line 173. I can tell that because I have ESP, but you might want to edit your question to include your current code so others can see what's going on.